# How to use third party javascript plugin in polymer 2.x

Tags: javascript, vaadin, polymer-2.x, vaadin10

Hello guys i have a trouble with using javascript plugin on polymer. How i include and use javascript plugin in my project.

```
@JavaScript("js/main.js")
```

this is my java class using javascript annotation. But its not working.

[image: Using javascript annotation in my class.]

And here is my html

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<dom-module id="main-page">
    <template>
        <style>
</style>
 </template>
    <script>
    class MainPage extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() {
            return 'main-page'
        }
    }

    customElements.define(MainPage.is, MainPage);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Any advice ?

Comment: I'm not fully sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. What is in main.js? Where are you importing the HTML file? 

If you are trying to create a custom HTML (Polymer) template that's bound to server side Java, this should be the right doc: https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/polymer-templates/tutorial-template-basic.html

Comment: I need to use http://idangero.us/swiper/ this plugin into my project but i can't using it with vaadin

Comment: @KhShuren-Erdene Can you please show your project's folder structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the JS file is not in the directory specified in the annotation.
Here is an example of project structure demonstrating `@JavaScript`

[image]

When you run that example, you should see the following in the browser.

[image]

You can find the sample project here: https://github.com/oluwasayo/demo-flow-js

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seems like my project structure a little bit wrong